# How can i get my required data from array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have array of objects like this

```
var a = [
 {'time' : 1539664755070,'T-1': 23 },
 {'time' : 1539665095442,'H-1': 24 },
 {'time' : 1539666489560,'T-1': 42 },
 {'time' : 1539665095442,'H-1': 27 },
 {'time': 1539671682230,'H-1': 40.45,'T-2': 33},
 {'time': 1539671682230,'T-2': 30.45,'T-1': 65},
 {'time': 1539671682230,'T-2': 42.45,'H-1': 11},
 {'time': 1539671682230,'T-1': 50.45,'T-2': 85}
];
```

I want to have data like this

```
data : {
  'T-1' : [23,42,50.45],
  'T-2' : [33,30.45,85],
  'H-1' : [24,27,40.45,11]
}
```

How can i get this data from given data?

Comment: Your expected output isn't valid syntactically. What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what's the problem in expected output?

Comment: The keys aren't valid identifiers; did you mean e.g. `'T-1': [...]`?

Comment: yes, i updated post

Comment: Are the keys static? meaning you expect `'T-1', 'T-2', and 'H-1'` every time?

Comment: No, its dynamic. See array 'a'. In array 'a' there can be other keys also than 'T-1','T-3'. array 'a' might have 'T-4', 'T-5'. Means it might be possible that in one object there might be only 2 keys like 'T-1', 'T-2' but it might be possible that in other object there might be more than 2 keys like  'T-3', 'H-1'

Comment: Okay, I just added my approach with comments explaining what I'm trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, if something is not clear, please lemme know:

```
const result = {};

a.forEach(object => {
    // Loop on each entry in the original array
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([key,value]) => {
      // Loop through each entry of one entry of the original array 
      // (ex 'T-1', 'T-2')
      if(key !== 'time') {
        // It's a key that I'm interested in, so do logic
        if(!result[key]) {
          // If the key (example 'T-1') haven't been encountered yet, 
          // initialize it's entry in the result with an empty array
          result[key] = [];
        }
        result[key].push(value);
      }  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = a.reduce((acc, row) => {
  // Loop over keys of each row.
  Object.keys(row)
    // Filter out the "time" keys.
    .filter((key) => key !== 'time')
    // Collect the values by key, storing them in the accumulator.
    .forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof acc[key] === 'undefined') {
        acc[key] = []
      }

      acc[key].push(row[key])
    })

  return acc
}, {})
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you add some info about what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()` to create a hash of your key and add the values corresponding to it. Then using `Object.assign()` and `spread syntax` you can create the final object.

```js
let data = [ {'time' : 1539664755070,'T-1': 23 }, {'time' : 1539665095442,'H-1': 24 }, {'time' : 1539666489560,'T-1': 42 }, {'time' : 1539665095442,'H-1': 27 }, {'time': 1539671682230,'H-1': 40.45,'T-2': 33}, {'time': 1539671682230,'T-2': 30.45,'T-1': 65},{'time': 1539671682230,'T-2': 42.45,'H-1': 11}, {'time': 1539671682230,'T-1': 50.45,'T-2': 85} ],
  result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(o).filter(k => k !== 'time');
    keys.forEach(key => {
      r[key] = r[key] || {[key] : []};
      r[key][key].push(o[key]);
    });
    return r;
  },{})));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best use case for using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of Key,Value arrays. Simplifies lot of things.